# New to java - Exception in thread “main” java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception

I'm new to Java - I've looked but can't seem to find whats wrong with this code.

```
import java.util.*;

class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please input grade");
        int grade = scan.nextInt();
        String gradeLevel = "Error";

        if ((grade > 100) || (grade < 0)) {
            System.out.println("Sorry please put a number between 0-100");
        } else if (grade > 90) {
            gradeLevel = "A";
        } else if (grade > 75) {
            gradeLevel = "B";
        } else if (grade > 49) {
            gradeLevel = "C";
        } else {
            gradeLevel = "F";
        }
        System.out.println("This student recieved " + gradeLevel + " for his/her grade");
    }
}
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at MyClass.main(Main.j`
```

Comment: What is the input?

Comment: you should close your scanner although it wouldnt cause your now exception.

Answer (score 2):

Code is working perfectly fine in Eclipse IDE, I'm using, with the most of the inputs I'm giving. I think you just look for whether System.in is available by using

System.out.println(System.in.available());

or use a generic function like scan.next();

Note: just close resources like Scanner classes, even though it will not cause any errors

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is an exception because System.in has an "end of file" status.
Here you are trying to get Input before you type.

1. Just try `scan.next ()` to resolve.
2. Please use a better IDE to resolve the expectations automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Initially it felt strange why you are getting this error, because I don't get it in my Eclipse IDE, but finally figured it out, I guess you should be using online IDE or something. You have to supply the input before starting the program. See the below screenshots and how I supply the value.

[image]

[image]

[image]